# Listener call being called recursively in google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, recursion, listener, coordinates

I'm trying to fix a listener issue in google maps.

onCameraChange is called every time that the map changes.

It seems like the camera isn't updating immediately using moveCamera, so when it starts to progressively change it calls the listener again.

If it isn't fully fixed, it will call the listener recursively- and eventually the map starts to stutter back and forth and finally crashes (presumably because of all the recursion.)

How can I prevent the listener from being called until the map is fully changed, or how can I immediately change the map instead of it gradually changing?

The values I'm using to check if it's out of bounds are:

```
VisibleRegion vr = mMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion();

double left = vr.latLngBounds.southwest.longitude;
double top = vr.latLngBounds.northeast.latitude;
double right = vr.latLngBounds.northeast.longitude;
double bottom = vr.latLngBounds.southwest.latitude;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onCameraChange is supposed to be called after the camera is done being animated or moved.

Sadly, that is not actually the case as I was able to see debugging.

Put a boolean (lets call it cameraMoving) - and put it around your listener method's activities with a default to false.

```
Listener onCameraChange(CameraPosition position){
    if (!cameraMoving){
        //code
    }
}
```

When you start to do the call, set the camera moving to true to prevent recursive actions and crashing.

```
map.animateCamera(update)
cameraMoving = true;
```

if you are okay with using GoogleMap.animateCamera instead of moveCamera - you can set a flag to keep track of if the camera is moving, and Override the GoogleMap.CancelableCallback methods.

```
@Override
    public void onFinish() {
        cameraMoving = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        //Code Here
    }
```

Then when the listener is called again it will only go through the code after the animation has finished by it calling the Override methods onFinish and onCancel

Read about it here: [Google Cancellable Callback](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.CancelableCallback)